# .net 6 core mvc return view() static file path gets the view path error : net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, .net-6.0

There is a problem with .net 6 core mvc when invoking a method of controller by (asp-controller ="test" asp-action="GetTest") static files such as js, css, media files in wwwroot path is getting the wrong path for example,
https://localhost:7261/curriculumvitae/assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.css
in this path curriculumvitae should be removed and the corret path is
https://localhost:7261/assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.css

how to remove it from the static path. that is view is directory. Briefly view directory should not be added to the static path.
I appreciate your valuble helpings.
with regards

[image]

Comment: Do you mean under `wwwroot` folder, you have folders `assets/plugins/global` in which `plugins.bundle.css` file is stored? What happens if you directly try to visit the file in the browser? do you need to go through `curriculumvitae`? If possible, could you please share the screenshot of the **Solution Explorer** along with wwwroot folder expanded all the way to the CSS file? It could give some more idea.

Comment: https://localhost:7261/curriculumvitae/assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.css I want to remove curriculumvitae from the path. that is path of view.

Comment: adding this ~/ solved

Comment: Thanks for updating us with the status of the issue. I would suggest you add your solution as an answer to this issue. It could help other community members in future with the similar issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~/ adding this to every static js file problem solved.